# Is there any way to css select between sibling and sibling?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In the case below,

```html
<h2 class='first'>h2</h2>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
<h2 class='second'>h2</h2>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
<h2 class='third'>h2</h2>
```

I'd like to select only p between h2.first and h2.second.
I tried select sibling but it selects all element after it.

Comment: Try h2:not(.third) ~ p, I think this will select the p not in h2.third.

Comment: Why not give the all the <p>s you want a class & select it?

Comment: @jms thank you, yeah it work! I wonder if there is a specific declaration to achieve that.

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed thank you, that is not what my situation is.

Comment: @ryuta69 I give you a sample code for presentation below as an answer, please take a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select every `p` after `.first`, change a property, and then `unset` every the property for every `p` after `.second`:

```css
h2.first ~ p {
  color: red;
}

h2.second ~ p {
  color: unset;
}
```

```html
<h2 class='first'>h2</h2>
<p>p</p>
<p>p</p>
<p>p</p>
<h2 class='second'>h2</h2>
<p>p</p>
<p>p</p>
<p>p</p>
<h2 class='third'>h2</h2>
```

Comment: thank you! your way looks like the closest to my ideal. And I understand there is no way to declare some two point to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have these p-Tags (without any other p-Tag before) you could use

```
p:nth-child(-n+3) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

This allows you to style your first 3 p-Tags because -n will go into the negative area (-0, -1, -2, -3, ...) while in the first case it will be -0 + 3 = 3, styling everything up to 3 which in this case are your first 3 p-Tags

Otherwise I would suggest using classes or ids in order to search up your DOM for the p-Tags you want to like for example with putting it into divs or expanding the h-Tag around the p-Tags.

Comment: thank you. I see, so I can't dynamically add p tag anymore...

Comment: @ryuta69 yes, which is why I would recommend you using classes/ids to get an unspecific amount of p-tags between the first and second h2. The solution Ori Drori suggested looks pretty clean for me

Answer (score 0):

here is a way you can apply css between siblings, in below example I am applying css to all p element siblings next to div.first and div.second:

```css
div.first + div.second p {
    color: tan;
}
```

```html
 <div class='first'>
  <h2 >h2</h2>
     <p>p</p>
     <p>p</p>
     <p>p</p>
 </div>
 <div class='second'>
  <h2 >h2</h2>
     <p>p</p>
     <p>p</p>
     <p>p</p>
 </div>
 <div class='third'>
  <h2 >h2</h2>
     <p>p</p>
     <p>p</p>
     <p>p</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have used CSS sibling selector `(~)`, like this:

`h2.first ~ p { color: blue}`

Answer (score 0):

You can select "~" selector for p that siblings of `.first` and `.second` then unset or give another color to the siblings p under `.third`.

Here's a representation, please take a look:

```css
h2:not(.third) ~ p {
  color: red;
}

h2.third ~ p {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h2 class='first'>h2</h2>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
<h2 class='second'>h2</h2>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
<h2 class='third'>h2</h2>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
    <p>p</p>
```

Comment: it's ideal. thank you. its unfortunate that there is no specific declaration, but useful.

Comment: Well, I'm glad it helped you :)